# C# сменить формат даты

Tags: c#, дата, валидация, время

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using DynamicPluginData;

namespace DatacolDynamicPluginNS
{
    public class DynamicPluginClass
    {
        public static string processDataFieldValue(string s, ItemInfo itemInfo, GlobalInfo globalInfo)
        {
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

s = 29.10.2017

Как сделать s = 2017-10-29
Спасибо.

Comment: Храните дату в типе `DateTime`, а вывод в нужном формате легко настраивается: [1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx), [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Спасибо, вроде работает. Но не могу подставить переменную, что бы компилятор брал значение s для конвертации. А статически да, работает. DateTime.ParseExact

Comment: public static string processDataFieldValue(string s, ItemInfo itemInfo, GlobalInfo globalInfo)
                                    {
                                       DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("29.10.2017", "dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                                       string x        = myDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                                       return x;
                                    }

Comment: ```s = string.Join("-", s.Split('.').Reverse());```